# Function us-central1-app does not exist, valid triggers are: europe-west1-app

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, firebase-hosting

I have firebase hosting and functions in the same project, where the hosting rewrites certain url requests to the function. It has been working well.

But after changing the region from `us-central1` to another region on the function, I am getting this error whenever I go to `http://localhost:5000/getoptions`

```
Function us-central1-app does not exist, valid triggers are: europe-west1-app
```

here is my rewrite code in firebase.json.

```
"rewrites": [
  {
    "source": "**",
    "function": "app"
  }
]

"rewrites": [
  {
    "source": "**",
    "function": "app"
  }
]
```

why isn't it showing the error? is there a way to specify redirect region too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After trying much, I found that as of 2021, firebase hosting rewrites to functions work for us-central1 region only. It's in the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/full-config)

[image: Firebase Hosting supports Cloud Functions in us-entral1 only]

So I had to remove those rewrites and use the full URL `https://europe-west1-[project name].cloudfunctions.net/app` to the function whenever I wanted to use my APIs in the deployed function.

Comment: Using the direct URL makes sense here as you are not serving webpages to users. For APIs direct URLs (or even callable functions) work perfectly.

Comment: Now you can keep your `rewrite` and add region. Eg.
```
{
  "source": "**",
  "function": "MyFunction",
  "region": "europe-west1"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had  a different error, google search ended up with this answer.

> Function us-central1-app does not exist, valid functions are:

In my case apparently I was using 'express' and installing it solved it.

```
npm install express
```

Answer (score 0):

If your issue is different than region related changes you can use

```
firebase login --reauth
```

This Works for most issues