# How to write redirect rules for Firebase Hosting and Express

Tags: node.js, firebase, express, google-cloud-functions, firebase-hosting

I am struggling to understand how `firebase.json` redirect rules work.

Here I define the `hosting` to my website, which works perfectly pointing to `dist/project-name` directory.

```
"hosting": [
{
  "target": "project-name",
  "public": "dist/project-name",
  "ignore": [
    "firebase.json",
    "**/.*",
    "**/node_modules/**"
  ],
 ...
 ...
```

However, things start to get confusing when I try to implement redirect rules. Let's say I want requests to non-existing files and directories be redirected to my hosting public target. I would assume that this is the proper way to define it:

```
"rewrites": [
    {
      "source": "**",
      "destination": "dist/project-name"
    }
  ]
```

But making requests to random endpoints like `localhost:5000/abcdef`, `localhost:5000/testing` are not being redirected so the request fails. What should the `source` be then?

Now, let's say that instead of redirecting to my public target directory, I want to redirect to a firebase function with Express.

```
"rewrites": [
    {
      "source": "**",
      "destination": "app"
    }
  ]
```

Well, that does not work either in the emulator localhost:5000. **Even though I can see functions work (Express app) in the emulator localhost:5001**

I am thinking because the `/functions` directory is not part of the `dist` folder. But then why redirecting to `dist/project-name` does not work either? Any ideas? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, I had to try a few things and read the documentation to understand what I was doing.

Docs:

1. https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/functions#use_a_web_framework
2. https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/full-config#rewrites

First, I was thinking that by doing `"destination": "dist/project-name"` in the `rewrites`, the url was **always** going to redirect to the hosting site. So no matter what path I go to (i.e. `/abc`) it was going to show me the `index.html` file. Well, that is not the case. The rewrite is not even happening and I could see that in the logs `http://localhost:4002/logs`. I think that is because of the [priority order](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/full-config#hosting_priority_order).

Second, my Express.js app is deployed as a function in firebase. Rewrites to Cloud Functions should be `"function": "app"` not `"destination": "app"`.

Last but not least, my Cloud Function with Express.js was deployed to `us-east1` like this `exports.app = functions.region("us-central1").https.onRequest(app);`. However, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68284811/4957620) we can see that Firebase Hosting only accepts `us-central1` for Cloud Functions at the moment.