# Rerouting Firebase Hosting to Express Cloud Functions

Tags: node.js, firebase, express, google-cloud-functions, firebase-hosting

I can't seem to configure routes to connect firebase hosting to my cloud function express app. I tried to setup as [shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44959652/firebase-hosting-with-dynamic-cloud-functions-rewrites) but the behaviour seems to be different. I can't seem to figure out what I am doing wrong. Please send help, I'm going insane.

**index.js**

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");

const app = require('./app');
exports.api = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

**app.js**

```
const app = express();
// ...
app.use(cors());
app.use('/params', paramsRoutes);
module.exports = app;
```

**firebase.json**

```
{
  "hosting": {
    // ...
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "/api/**",
        "function": "api"
      },
     // ...
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: do let me know if my recommendations in the answer below were helpful.

Answer (score 1):

There is appropriate [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/functions) that lists your requirement of hosting the Cloud Functions in Firebase Hosting using a custom domain.

- Make sure that you have the latest version of the Firebase CLI and
  that you've initialized Firebase Hosting.
- Initialize Cloud Functions by running the following command from the
  root of your project directory: `firebase init functions`

Also as per [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/functions#use_a_web_framework)we can use rewrites to serve requests for a specific firebase hosting URL to a function. To do that you need to use "/api". You don't have to add the entire URL because you are redirecting from firebase hosting. So, when you add "/api" you are indicating to redirect requests going to "PROJECT_ID.web.app/api and PROJECT_ID.firebaseapp.com/api" to the function you specified.
If you want [redirect every single URL to your host to an express app](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/full-config#rewrite-functions) in Cloud Functions, you will need to do the following:

- Make sure there is no index.html in your public hosting folder
  (otherwise it will always be served with the path /).
- Your Express routes need to exactly match the incoming URL, not just
  the wildcard part.

You can read more in the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events) or follow [this medium post](https://codeburst.io/express-js-on-cloud-functions-for-firebase-f76b5506179) for more details.
Check these links for similar implementation:

- [How to write redirect rules for Firebase hosting and express](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71740476/how-to-write-redirect-rules-for-firebase-hosting-and-express)
- [How to redirect all server requests to a function in firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50071338/how-to-redirect-all-server-requests-to-a-function-in-firebase-hosting)